# Facebook MessengerExtensions in Browser?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Attempting to load the [Facebook MessengerExtensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions) appears not to work when using the in-browser experience for Facebook messenger (as opposed to the native apps on iOS or Android).  When I interact with my bot's persistent menu to open a webview (that is trying to use MessengerExtensions), I get this error in the browser console of a newly opened tab:

`Messenger Extensions are not enabled - could be "messenger_extensions" was not set on a url, the domain was not whitelisted or this is an outdated version of Messenger client`

I have the impression that MessengerExtensions is simply not supported for the in-browser experience but have a couple of questions:

1. Can someone find where in the docs this lack of support is stated (because I've obviously missed it if it's there...)?
2. If this is supported somehow, suggestions for what I might be doing wrong? (I have confirmed that my persistent menu button has `messenger_extensions: true` and my `web_url` is whitelisted...)
3. Is there some kind of workaround (not using MessengerExtensions) for the webview opened in the browser to get the page-scoped user Id (PSUID) for the user interacting with the bot?

   - For a button generated with the Send API I could conceivably append the PSUID to the URL being opened as a query param (not sure of security considerations on that)
   - For the persistent menu the `web_url` of the button action is **NOT** dynamic (it's configured ahead of time) so **I'm unsure how this URL when opened from the browser-based messenger interface is supposed to figure out what user opened it**.  Thoughts/Ideas?

Comment: on which device are you testing the webview

Comment: @aidonsnous I've tested use of the extensions **successfully** on Android.  This question is about use of the Messenger Extensions with Facebook's **in-browser** messenger experience e.g. on facebook.com

Comment: Were you able to fix it? Can it work on a browser?

Comment: @ItzikGili Nope... I haven't come back to this since posting but I never did find an answer on this

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried it on the chrome with facebook api version 2.10, and it works. When I clicked on the button, I got a "lightbox" looking window that opened on top of the messenger, and all the proper callbacks are called in javascript.

this is my button json:

```
{
      type: 'web_url',
      title: <title>,
      url: <url>,
      messenger_extensions: true,
      fallback_url: <url>,
      webview_height_ratio: 'tall'
}
```

these are a few things that I did:

- the button spec should contain `messenger_extensions: true`
- facebook `whitelisted_domains` doesn't do subdomains, so make sure you whitelist the entire url before the parameters.
- `fallback_url` should be whitelisted as well.